# declaring and using a map<string, string> in c++

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

I am a C++ beginner, trying to declare and use a map, but despite checking tutorials and similar questions, I have not managed to make it compile yet.

Here is a minimal example, also in [ideone](http://ideone.com/Kp0EPh).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bits/stl_map.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    //  error: ‘_Rb_tree’ does not name a type
    map<string, string> dictionary;
    // dictionary["value 1"] = "value 2";
    // dictionary.insert(pair<string, string>("value 3", "value 4"));
    // dictionary.insert(make_pair("value 5", "value 6"));
    return 0;
}
```

The next problem will be to insert data and I've seen three ways, as in the comments above. Which one should I choose? Are those ways all equivalent or not?

Comment: You should probably include `<map>`, not `<bits/stl_map.h>`.

Comment: You have to `#include <map>` and not include `<bits/stl_map.h>`.

Comment: my problem is now solved, so no complaints. However I don't understand why this question was closed as off-topic, since I've provided a minimal example which reproduces the problem, including runnable code in ideone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    map<string, string> dictionary;
    dictionary["value 1"] = "value 2";
    dictionary.insert(pair<string, string>("value 3", "value 4"));
    dictionary.insert(make_pair("value 5", "value 6"));
    return 0;
}
```

Works fine for me, you needed to include the map header. It could also not find #include "bits/stl_map.h". I am not sure if that is a local file of yours.

Comment: yes, I had the wrong include... it works now. so all three ways to insert data are equivalent?

Comment: @stivlo They are NOT equivilent. Insert won't change the map if the value already exists.

Comment: oh OK, so square brackets overwrites the value, insert adds a value, but does not overwrite, and the two ways to create a pair, are equivalent, is this correct now?

Comment: @stivlo The two ways to create the pair are logically equivalent. make_pair could result in some temporary copies but this may be fixed in C++11.

Answer (score 0):

I personally prefer the second one. It's a bit bulky, but it's clear what you're doing.

I wouldn't worry about the difference in performance if I were you, you can always benchmark it, but in the end these things don't make or break your code.

See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/operator[]

So, choose whichever you find most clear/convenient!